# jsp solution for inheritance object

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc

what is the best practice for showing/receiving input for the super class
example

```
public class person {
private int personId;
}

public class employee extends person {
private String name;
}
```

if i want to fill name, it should be

```
<form:input path="name"/>
```

but how to input for personId ?

Comment: employee should not extend person. employement is a relationship between an organization and a person. or employee is a role played by a person

Comment: its just a sample. not a real class